# Coloring a cell within a range, if the same cell within an identical range on a different worksheet is already colored?

Tags: excel, vba

In VBA, I am flagging results within a range and coloring them green based on cell value (ex. value < "28"). Each sheet (of four total) corresponds to a different marker and is flagged green based on a value. All the sheets have an identical X and Y axis, with the range of interest being identical between sheets (B2:BJ26). I would like to make a fifth sheet that colors the corresponding cell green if all four other corresponding cells from the other sheets are colored green.

I could do this cell by cell....

Simplified example

```
If Sheets(A) "B2" value < 30 AND Sheets(B) "B2" Value > 1.1 AND Sheets(C) "B2" Value < 1500 AND Sheets(D) "B2" Value > 0.30 THEN Sheets(E) "B2" interior.color = RGB(0,255,0)
```

But there must be a more efficient way for all cells within the B2:BJ26 range. Someone more skilled, please help me.

Example of working code I'm using to color/flag values on the first four sheets.

```
Worksheets("Sheet 1").Activate

Dim XXXXXXX As Range, cell As Range
Set XXXXXXX = Range("B2:BJ26")

For Each cell In XXXXXXX

If cell.Value < "28" And cell.Value > "1" Then
        cell.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
    End If

Next
```

Answer (score 1):

This code did the job for me. Let me know if it gave you the results you expected.

```
Option Explicit

Sub ColorSheetFive()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim m As Integer
    Dim n As Integer
    Dim allGreen As Boolean

    For m = 2 To 26
        For n = 2 To 62
            allGreen = True
            For i = 1 To 4
                If Sheets(i).Cells(m, n).Interior.Color <> RGB(0, 255, 0) Then
                    allGreen = False
                End If
            Next i
            If allGreen Then
                Sheets(5).Cells(m, n).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
            End If
        Next n
    Next m

    MsgBox "Color checking complete!"

End Sub
```

Comment: You could shorten it slightly by exiting the for loop when a non-green colour is found.

Comment: I thought about this, but the macro ran so quickly when I tested it that the time saved was barely worth the effort of tapping it out on the keyboard.

Comment: For some reason, this code is not working for me. The code runs fine, but no cells within the designated range are colored green.

Comment: @JakeKurdys, you'll need to set the RBG values according to what you find in the first four sheets. At the moment it's set to pure green (RGB(0,255,0)), but this may not be the green you have in your cell.